# using Onclick, fetch api data in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, random, fetch

I am new to React Native.
I am facing an issue with this view. Basically it is something like this when you click a button it generates any random number, now this random number becomes an id and it goes to at the end of the API url, And using this new API - with ID at the end of it. -  data gets fetched. Now i've divided this task in two parts generating random number code (i.e. snippet 1) and fetching data from api ( i.e. snippet 2). As of now, I don't know how to combine them because i am new to react native so a little help here would be appreciated from anyone.

**Snipppet 1**

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
export default class MyProject extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      // This is our Default number value
      NumberHolder : 0
    }
  }
GenerateRandomNumber=()=>
{
var RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1 ;
this.setState({
  NumberHolder : RandomNumber
})
}
  render() {
    return (  
      <View style={styles.MainContainer} >
       <Text style={{marginBottom: 10, fontSize: 20}}>{this.state.NumberHolder}</Text>
       <Button title="Generate Random Number" onPress={this.GenerateRandomNumber} />      
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create(
{
  MainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
});
```

**Snippet 2**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Box, FlatList, Center, NativeBaseProvider, Button } from "native-base";
import { StyleSheet, View, ActivityIndicator, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function MyFUnction() {
  
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/7");
    const data = await resp.json();
    setData(data);
    setVisible(false);
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.list}>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <Center flex={1}>
        {visible && <Button onPress={() => fetchData()}>Press</Button>}
        {data && (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={(item) => this.renderItem(item)}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          />
        )}
      </Center>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    paddingVertical: 4,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You make 2 components and don't call any of them in the other!! You must make one component fo this as you say before! Or when you make 2, You must call one of them in the other! Is this helpful or I write the code in the answer box?

Comment: tbh, i cant understand clearly this question. you need passing that random number to snippet 2 ? or something else?

Comment: @Mohamadamin, In code it would be great. Beacuase what you just said is above my level.

Comment: @Edofx I want to use this snippet together that means when a button pressed a rondom number generates and it passed to API. I know how to pass it to the API. but the problem is Snipppet 1 is a class while 2 is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must understand **components** clearly! **React is component based**! *But your case is not 2 components*! You have a component for fetching api and showing in list! Generating a random number is not a component, but it is a method(or function) in your list component! I think it is better to use one component for list and wrap a function to it for generating random number.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Box, FlatList, Center, NativeBaseProvider, Button } from "native-base";
import { StyleSheet, View, ActivityIndicator, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function MyFUnction() {
  
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  const generatRandomNumber = () => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1
  }
  
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/${generatRandomNumber()}`);
    const data = await resp.json();
    setData(data);
    setVisible(false);
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.list}>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <Center flex={1}>
        {visible && <Button onPress={() => fetchData()}>Press</Button>}
        {data && (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={(item) => this.renderItem(item)}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          />
        )}
      </Center>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    paddingVertical: 4,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

But if you want to passing data between components you are have, it is not related to function or class component and you can pass data between them with props! So your code like this:

**Random Number Component**

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
export default class MyProject extends Component {
  constructor(props){ //edited
    super(props); //edited
    this.state={
      // This is our Default number value
      NumberHolder : 0
    }
  }
GenerateRandomNumber=()=>
{
var RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1 ;
this.props.randomNumber(RandomNumber)
}
  render() {
    return (  
      <View style={styles.MainContainer} >
       <Text style={{marginBottom: 10, fontSize: 20}}>{this.state.NumberHolder}</Text>
       <Button title="Generate Random Number" onPress={this.GenerateRandomNumber} />      
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create(
{
  MainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
});
```

**Your list component:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Box, FlatList, Center, NativeBaseProvider, Button } from "native-base";
import { StyleSheet, View, ActivityIndicator, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
// import MyProject
export default function MyFUnction() {
  
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(null);    

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/${number}`);
    const data = await resp.json();
    setData(data);
    setVisible(false);
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.list}>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <Center flex={1}>
      <MyProject radomNumber={(number) => setNumber(number)}
        {visible && <Button onPress={() => fetchData()}>Press</Button>}
        {data && (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={(item) => this.renderItem(item)}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          />
        )}
      </Center>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    paddingVertical: 4,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Comment: thanks for replying. as you said, I applied this and I am getting this error. I imported MyProject class in your "Your list component" code snippet and it is saved in app.js. Can you tell me what i am missing here?
_this.props.randomNumber is not a function. (In '_this.props.randomNumber(RandomNumber)', '_this.props.randomNumber' is undefined)

Comment: Answer edited!!

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for helping me.
here i am posting answer to my question, if anybody in future need an answer.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, View, Button, FlatList, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
 
export default class MyProject extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={

      // This is our Default number value
      NumberHolder : 1,
      books: []

    }
  }

GenerateRandomNumber=()=>
{
var RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1;
fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/${RandomNumber}`)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then(booksList => {
    this.setState({ books: booksList });
});
this.setState({
  NumberHolder : RandomNumber

})
}

  render() {
    let Image_Http_URL ={ uri: 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/react_thumb_install.png'};
    return (
   
      <View style={styles.MainContainer} >

       <Text style={{marginBottom: 10, fontSize: 20}}>{this.state.NumberHolder}</Text>
<Image
   style={{width: '100%', height: 200,resizeMode : 'stretch' }}
   source={{uri: this.state.books.url}} 
 />   
      <Text style={{marginBottom: 10, fontSize: 12}}>{this.state.books.title}</Text>
      <Text style={{marginBottom: 10, fontSize: 12}}>{this.state.books.url}</Text>
      <Text style={{marginBottom: 10, fontSize: 12}}>{this.state.books.thumbnailUrl}</Text>
       <Button title="Generate Random Number" onPress={this.GenerateRandomNumber} />
        
      </View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
{
  MainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }

});
```